# How to upgrading Docker Odoo CE to EE

Tags: docker, odoo

I'm trying to upgrade my local Odoo CE 14.0 to Enterprise, i follow this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eCHJAq1QdY and official steps https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/administration/maintain/enterprise.html

But when i trying to instal web_enterpsie module get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 347, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 912, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 531, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1398, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1386, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 399, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 386, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-71>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 475, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 593, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 89, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 461, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 349, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 198, in load_module_graph
    registry.setup_models(cr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 276, in setup_models
    model._setup_fields()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 2845, in _setup_fields
    field.setup_full(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 401, in setup_full
    self._setup_related_full(model)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/fields.py", line 458, in _setup_related_full
    field = model.pool[model_name]._fields[name]
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
KeyError: 'avatar_128'
odoo.conf:

addons_path = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons,/mnt/extra-addons/enterprise,/mnt/extra-addons/custom
```

Anybody could help me please ?

Comment: Are the comunity and enterprice modules from same time. What happens when you try `-u web` istead of `-i web_enterprise`?